# SQLite substring search query doesn't work

Tags: sqlite, search, kotlin, substring

I am trying to do a substring search.. and I am trying to ignore the upper/lower case.. but it does not work.. the databse returns nothing. 
But when removing the "%" and the last parameter -sort order-  then it works.

the problem is in the else-statement. It does not give any error.

Could you please take a look at my code and see if there is smthg wrong. thank 
you.

**MainActivity.kt**

```
....
        override fun onQueryTextChange(newText: String?): Boolean {
            if (newText == null || newText == ""){
                cursor = dbManager.queryData()
            }
            else{
                cursor = dbManager.queryData(null, DbManager.colText + "=?", arrayOf(newText+"%"), DbManager.colTime + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC;")
            }
            ctAdapter.swapCursor(cursor)
            return true
        }
    })
```

**DbManager.kt**

```
fun queryData(projection:Array<String>? = null, selection:String? = null, selectionArgs:Array<String>? = null,  sortOrder:String? = null):Cursor{
    val cursor = sqlDB!!.query(dbTable, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder)
    return cursor
}
```

Comment: try escaping the `%`. so instead of how you have it try `"\%"`

Comment: @Rafa unfortunately it did not work.. btw. thank U for the answer